# How can I connect multiple monitors to one PC?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors

I am currently trying to use one PC and 5 separate monitors to display content using a digital signage software.

I was told that each monitor will be seen by Windows and given an index number to identify the display in which the content should be pushed. My question is what hardware should I use to get this done. Is there a 4 port DVI or VGA graphics card or all in one workstation that will handle this application?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your budget, configuration of your current system, performance requirements, etc. The options are:

- single card which would support all 5 monitors, like [AMD
  Eyefinity](http://www.amd.com/us/products/technologies/amd-eyefinity-technology/Pages/eyefinity.aspx). For example [PowerColor AX7870 2GBD5-6D](https://www.google.com/shopping/product/6712946505196087667), which starts from $350
- multiple cards with just 2 connectors
- and if you don't have enough slots available - you could use USB-to-DVI adapters

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at the higher end NVIDIA graphics cards.....

Comment: Why the downgrade?  NVIDIA does have a 4 Port display card!

Comment: Yes NVIDIA does, and it is awesome, lol. I gave you a +1 but I would have linked to the card (that doesn't violate tos I hope) http://www.nvidia.com/object/product_quadro_nvs_420_us.html